# Turn six flat shapes into a cube

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I opened my calendar today and it had a puzzle inside. There are six pieces, and I suppose I have to make them into a cube... I tried to solve it and failed hard. So I decided to try to solve it with programming....

I made them into polygons (not sure if that was a good idea), but have no clue how to rotate them and/or check if any shape collides with any other shape.

The shapes are these:

[image]

TL;DR: I'm looking for help with checking every possible combination of these shapes to see if they make a cube. In other words, how can I rotate and check polygons (or something else that represents these pieces) for intersection?

Comment: How does this apply to Java?

Comment: Anything to do with programming at all ?

Comment: Unless his calendar is part of his Java homework(?).

Comment: I'm looking for help to check every possible combination of those shapes to see if it makes a cube

Comment: And what's your question?  See [Code golf SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yours is an algorithm question, not a Java-specific code question.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried nothing, since I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: @ruakh are you sure? it seems to **almost** fit in a 4x4 cube from what I've managed with the pieces

Comment: the 2nd piece is a 3x4 piece, so I suppose it lines up with the 5th one(?)

Comment: I have this physical puzzle. The parts should be thick, not thin. Actually they made of some sort of rubber.

Comment: @Dims Yeah, they are ca. 0.7cm thick, but I don't think that matters... _You wouldn't happen to have the solution do you?_

Comment: It's simple. You mean programmatic solution? Wait.

Comment: I did write something which fitted 4x4 shapes into a 3x3 cube folding over at corners, but that requires that the shapes will fit. I couldn't work out why your polygons would not fit, as it found solutions to other cases, but then added a sanity check and your polygons have 56 unit squares rather than 54.

Comment: It's name is Happy cube, found it in Wikipedia and Google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Cube

Comment: @Dims: Thanks, that makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

Making them into polygons is not the correct abstraction for this problem.

See, what you have are the 6 sides of the cube, but now you have to figure out how to rotate them. Each polygon has on its edge 12 small squares that are either on or off and must match with the ones next to it. This is a very discrete problem.

The entire cube has 8 (vertices) + 12 * 2 (edges) small cubes on the edges.

Each face, when placed into the cube, will occupy some of those small cubes.

You need to
1) make a mapping that maps the face into the whole cube on the given face, in the given orientation
2) do a search for the configuration where no small cubes are occupied twice.